# Adding route in windows xp

Tags: networking, windows-xp, routing

In XP, I am trying to add a static route for a network with subnet mask. I tried issuing the command:

```
C:\>route add 10.3.0.1 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.1.0.1
```

I get the error:

> The route addition failed: The specified mask parameter is invalid.
>   (Destination & Mask) != Destination.

I used same command in win 7 and route was added to windows successfully, but in win xp the error is thrown. Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You cant use a gateway that is located in a different subnet. Either your gateway ip has to be 10.3.x.x OR your mask has to be 255.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

If you specify 255.255.0.0 as mask, you are having a class B subnet. So you should use 10.3.**0.0** as subnet address.

Answer (score 1):

The mask `255.255.0.0` indicates that your network goes from `10.3.0.1` to `10.3.255.255`, and the default gateway is `10.1.0.1`, that is outside of your network.

Check the mask or the default gateway address that you want to use.

Comment: 10.3.0.1 is the network i want to add and its subnet is 255.255.0.0 and 10.1.0.1 is my network and gateway router and its subnet is same both network are connected through MPLS

Comment: Change the mask to 255.0.0.0, so your network will go from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 and your default gateway will be inside the network.

Comment: As a general rule, the default gateway MUST be inside the network range.

Comment: My default gateway is 10.1.0.1 is it not in subnet 255.255.0.0?

Comment: The subnet is a "mask" that is been applied over the IP address. If  I have for example, address 192.168.2.56 with mask 255.255.0.0 it means that my network goes from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255.

Comment: Combining 10.3.0.1 with the mask 255.255.0.0 means the network goes from 10.3.0.0 to 10.3.255.255

Comment: ok i got it i used 10.3.0.0 as destination and it worked thanks for your help and info